# Meaning of "by" in the phrase "by the age of eight"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This question is related to this other one: "[What does “by” mean if we are talking about a date?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87002/what-does-by-mean-if-we-are-talking-about-a-date?newreg=6c3a7c240bae4345b7f92de382b6ef36)".

What is the most common interpretation of the phrase "by the age of eight"? Does it mean before the person's eighth birthday? Or does it mean before they stop being eight, namely before their ninth birthday? The answer may possibly vary by context.

As a native speaker, I feel it should mean before their ninth birthday. To use an analogy, if A says "by the age of 18, a person ought to have done a double back somersault", and then B manages to do their first double back somersault when they are 18 and a half, I would make the interpretation that B has lived up to A's spoken expectation. But perhaps others differ?

Comment: I don't think it's that exact. An eight-year-old child (in their ninth year) would be expected to have reached a certain stage of development or education.

Comment: By the age of = by the time the person becomes that age. I've never heard of people saying "by the age of eight" and meaning "hey, I really meant before you become nine."

Comment: @Kate - What is your condition clause?

Comment: @FeliniusRex - That meaning is very common - for example, a websearch company served me up with [this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-47317891) as a top result, which goes to [this](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanpsy/article/PIIS2215-0366(19)30031-8/fulltext). To replicate the search, click [here](https://www.google.com/search?q="by+the+age+of+18"&complete=no).

Comment: @ruffle -- Where I live and in my experience (SE US), this usage is unknown. If I had to put money on it, I'd bet this is yet another BrE/AmE difference.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - You may be right about that. In USEng there is also the usage of "through" to mean "up to and including", which doesn't exist in BrE. Perhaps BrE stretches the use of "by" to cover a similar meaning (although not an identical one, because it refers to single events rather than repeated events or continuous states) that doesn't exist or rarely exists for "by" in USEng.

Comment: If the child develops normally! I associate expressions such as 'by the age of X' with information about the expected level of physical or social development, or education, of children of different ages. I'm no paediatrician, but I assume such pronouncements refer to the year during which the child is eight (their ninth year) rather than a definite cut-off date.

Comment: What I remain unclear about is whether the other interpretation of "by the age of eight", namely as meaning before they are _eight_, is common among people who do not fall into the category of computer programmers motivated by some kind of literalism who insist that "_by_ means < and therefore the meaning is obvious".

Comment: Another question: "[A short way of saying “when a child is 1 or 2” (or “0 or 1 or 2”) that mentions 2 but not 3?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283971)".