# A short way of saying "when a child is 1 or 2" (or "0 or 1 or 2") that mentions 2 but not 3?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [this other question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283794/meaning-of-by-in-the-phrase-by-the-age-of-eight?noredirect=1#comment530122_283794) I asked how people would interpret the word "by" in the phrase "by the age of eight". It seems there are different interpretations: some read the phrase as meaning "before the eighth birthday", others as "before the ninth birthday".

OK, so is there a way to communicate the sense of "**when a child is 1 or 2**" or "**before a child stops being two**"? I am looking for a phrase that

- mentions the number 2 and not 3;
- is short;
- can convey the meaning of "at the age of either 1 or 2" or the meaning of "before the child is 3.00" - it doesn't matter whether an age of less than 12 months is ruled in or out or whether there is a lack of clarity about that young age; what matters is that the "cut-off" point is 3.00 and the number 2 is mentioned, not 3.

Comment: Is the child two or less?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most natural ways to express the meaning would be things like "before her third birthday", or "by her third birthday", or "before turning 3", all of which mention 3 and not 2.

But respecting your constraint of mentioning 2 and not 3, one could say "while aged 1 or 2", or "at the age of 1 or 2".